# ios - Cannot click first item in radlistview

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I cannot click the first item in a `RadListView`. However it works well in `android`.

In this code, `onitemSelected` is not called on the first item

```
<RadListView
    class="jobs"
    row="1"
    loadOnDemandMode="Auto"
    pullToRefresh="true"
    selectionBehavior="Press"
    [items]="jobPaginator.docs"
    (itemSelected)="onItemSelected($event)"
    (loadMoreDataRequested)="onLoadMoreItemsRequested($event)"
    (pullToRefreshInitiated)="onPullToRefreshInitiated($event)">
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
      <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="jobs__card">
        <Label class="jobs__card-customer-name" [text]="item.customerName"></Label>
        <Label class="jobs__card-device-model" [text]="item.deviceModel"></Label>
        <Label class="jobs__card-store-name" [text]="item.storeName"></Label>
        <Label class="jobs__card-customer-email" [text]="item.email"></Label>
        <Label class="jobs__card-customer-phone" [text]="item.phone"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </RadListView>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to share your code on this

Comment: @david I added my code